# Initialize MutableStateMapOf variable with a for loop in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Kotlin and JetPack Compose to create an app and I have an issue. It could be a tiny one because I'm still a beginner with these technologies.

**The Problem:**

I would like to create a StateMap to track the states of several composables. I know I have to use the `remember` keyword to prevent recomposition from forgetting states.

I could easily instantiate my MutableStateMap like that:

```
val expandedStates = remember {
       mutableStateMapOf(
            "category1" to false, 
            "category2" to false,
            "category3" to false, 
            "category4" to false, 
            "category5" to false,
        )
}
```

But how could I do if I want to use a for loop instead of explicitly describe the Map keys:values ?
I was expecting something like that :

```
val categories = ListOf( "cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat5")

val expandedStates = remember {
       mutableStateMapOf(
            for (cat in categories){
              return Pair(cat, false)
            }
        )
}
```

Maybe I should override the constructor of the MutableStateMap class to allow it to accept this for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
val categories = ListOf( "cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat5")

val expandedStates = remember {
    mutableStateMapOf(*categories.map { it to false }.toTypedArray())
}
```

If you have a more complex case where you can't use a `map` operator and actually need a for loop, you could build a list and then pass it in:

```
val expandedStates = remember {
    val pairsList = buildList {
        for (cat in categories){
           add(Pair(cat, false))
        }
    }
    mutableStateMapOf(*pairsList.toTypedArray())
}
```

For regular maps, there is a `buildMap` function. You could write a helper function to build a mutable State Map:

```
inline fun <K, V> buildMutableStateMap(builderAction: MutableMap<K, V>.() -> Unit): SnapshotStateMap<K, V> =
    mutableStateMapOf(*buildMap(builderAction).toList().toTypedArray())
```

and then use it like:

```
val expandedStates = remember {
    buildMutableStateMap {
        for (cat in categories){
           put(cat, false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The first solution solved my problem. But I have another issue with this variable :

```
val rotationStates by remember {
        mutableStateMapOf(
            *categories.map {
                it to animateFloatAsState(targetValue = if(expandedStates[it] == true) 180f else 0f)
            }.toTypedArray()
        )
    }
```
The animateFloatAsState seems not working properly and I have this error : 
Composable calls are not allowed inside the calculation parameter of inline fun <T> remember(calculation: () -> TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T)
What does it means?

Comment: `animateFloatAsState` is a Composable, so you can only directly call it in a Composable function. Logically it doesn't really make sense to put state inside state. I'm not sure of the best way of handling what you're trying to do. Maybe move the `animateFloatAsState` down into wherever you are creating whatever UI is using the categories.

Comment: Yes I see. Sorry I mixed a little too much notions. But it's good now my code is working as expected! Thank you again :)